# snakemake. How to pass target from command line when creating multiple targets

Tags: snakemake

With help following a previous question, this code creates targets (copies of the file named "practice_phased_reversed.vcf" in each of two directories.

```
dirs=['k_1','k2_10']
rule all:
        input:
                expand("{f}/practice_phased_reversed.vcf",f=dirs)
rule r1:
        input:
                "practice_phased_reversed.vcf"
        output:
                "{f}/{input}"
        shell:
               "cp {input} {output}"
```

However, I would like to pass the target file on the snakemake command line.
I tried this (below), with the command "snakemake practice_phased_reversed.vcf",  but it gave an error : "MissingRuleException: No rule to produce practice_phased_reversed.vcf"

```
dirs=['k_1','k2_10']
rule all:
        input:
                expand("{f}/{{base}}_phased_reversed.vcf",f=dirs)
rule r1:
        input:
                "{base}_phased_reversed.vcf"
        output:
                "{f}/{input}"
        shell:
               "cp {input} {output}"
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the target file name as configuration option on the command line and use that option to construct the file names in the Snakefile:

```
target = config['target']

dirs = ['k_1','k2_10']

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{f}/%s" % target, f=dirs),

rule r1:
    input:
        target,
    output:
        "{f}/%s" % target,
    shell:
       "cp {input} {output}"
```

To be executed as:

```
snakemake -C target=practice_phased_reversed.vcf
```

Comment: thanks,  running that begets error: MissingInputException in line 9 of /home/tuf29449/r/snakemakework/temp/Snakefile: Missing input files for rule r1: practice_phase_reversed.vcf

Answer (score 0):

Your target file `practice_phased_reversed.vcf` doesn't satisfy `output` requirements of `rule r1`. It is missing wildcard value for `{f}`.

Instead this following example, `snakemake data/practice_phased_reversed.vcf`, where `data` matches wildcard `f`,  will work as expected.

Code:

```
rule r1:
        input:
                "{base}_phased_reversed.vcf"
        output:
                "{f}/{base}_phased_reversed.vcf"
        shell:
               "cp {input} {output}"
```

Comment: WildcardError in line 7 of /home/tuf29449/r/snakemakework/temp/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'base'

Comment: I updated my answer with the code I used. Your question is the first time I learnt `{input}` can be used as wildcard directly in `output:`. In my testing, such usage is successful if input file doesn't have any wildcard. That is, if `{base}` in input is replaced with `practice` in your example code, it works as expected. Not sure why.

Comment: That runs,  thanks.  But I need to be able to use the list of directories, and have the operation done to each of them.   My full application has over 15 directories to be written to.  thoughts?

Comment: If you are asking how to use snakefile by defining target files within the file itself, they need to be defined properly in `rule all`. This is not the case in your example code, as there is no value provided for wildcard `{base}`. What is the value of `{base}`? Is it directory name dependent?

Comment: The goal is to have the directories given in the snakefile,  but have target file(s) (that will be copied to those directories,  given on the command line using a wildcard.   Hope that is clear.

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question with these specifics.

Comment: Thanks.  going around in circles,  as I've already posted versions of this question twice.

Comment: I understand your frustration. However, adding specific examples would help. For example, add your current code and specific input and output filenames. PS- if you haven't see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet, giving it a quick read would help.

Comment: I made a new question, and rephrased things. Hopefully it is more clear.